# meaning of the word "some" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> "Right," says Dracula, slamming the front door. "I've decided to stay. Pull down the window shades quickly— quickly! Let's move it!"
>
> "What window shades?" asks the baker.
>
> "There are none, right? Figures. You got a basement in this joint?"
>
> "No," says the wife affably, "I'm always telling Jarslov to build one but he never listens. That's **some** Jarslov, my husband."

Dose it mean: It is **very good** to have basement? 
Dose "some" means: very good?

Comment: The only possible meaning I can find in it would be "My husband is a remarkable Jarslov". I am taking the colloquial meaning of _some_ as "a remarkable example" - similar to "quite a" But unless there is some special context (eg there had already been a discussion of the Jarslov family) this makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, she is discussing with her husband and it make no sense if we say she means: her husband is remarkable,  so I guess she means: it is very good to have basement in their house.

Comment: No, @Viser Hashemi, from what you say, that is not what it means. The fact that she is always telling him to build one means that she thinks a basement would be good. What "That's some Jarslov" appears to mean is something like "The Jarslovs never do what you ask them to, and my husband is such a Jarslov that he won't do it even when I keep telling him to". He is extreme even by Jarslov standards.

Comment: Lots of thanks, @Colin Fine. I got it. You mean: Jarslov is her housband's family name and amongst Jarslovs her housband is special, I mean his attitudes are extreme.

Comment: I think that must be what it means, yes. It's not obvious, but maybe it would be in context.